# phpunit zf2 - class not found

Tags: zend-framework2, phpunit, autoloader

I get this message when trying to test a controller.

```
 Fatal error: Class 'Zend\Test\PHPUnit\Controller\AbstractHttpControllerTestCase' not     found in
```

However I have configured an autoloader and instanciated a zend class before this point. Doesn't make much sense to me

EDIT

actually the zend\test isn't included I'm using an older version of zf2 from 17th oct 2012 just a git clone. But that doesn't contain the tests. They were added later but I have to find out where from to get a test component compatible with the main library release. It's quite annoying. I guess the answer is in a git merge somewhere.

EDIT

so i had been using a recent version of zf2 but switched to working with an older version before they had included the zend\test. they included the zend\test a month later so i went used git to check it out from that time and use it to test my routers

obviously this isn't prefect since the release date of my zf2 precedes the zend\test but it seems to work fine and i keep the tests in a different suite

Comment: Need to see some code, how are you instantiating your controller to test?

Comment: If the answer is in git merge somewhere (as you coin it), *git diff* is your friend.